# Preseed ignoring "disable_dhcp"

Tags: vmware, debian, preseed

I'm trying to preseed a VM on an ESXi server, using Packer. Problem I'm having right now is that whatever the options I've put in the preseed file (see below), the installer keeps telling me that no DHCP was answer and comes up with a dialog box to let me select the network configuration.

Needless to say, I intend on using those templates (JSON + preseed) to deploy tens of VMs. This is a no-go if I keep being asked for the proper DHCP config, right ?

Here's a snippet of the JSON (Packer) file where it passes the kernel params to grub, followed by a snippet from my preseed file. If anyone has an idea, please let me know.

**JSON : minimalOS.json**

```
},
    "boot_command" :
    [
        "<esc><wait>", "install <wait>",
        "preseed/url=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/preseed.cfg <wait>",
        "debian-installer=en_US <wait>", "auto <wait>", "locale=en_US <wait>",
        "kbd-chooser/method=us <wait>", "keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap=us <wait>",
        "fb=false <wait>", "debconf/frontend=noninteractive <wait>",
        "console-setup/ask_detect=false <wait>", "console-keymaps-at/keymap=us <wait>",
        "<enter><wait>"
    ]
```

**The preseed file : preseed.cfg**

```
# We don't want to be bothered with trivial questions
d-i debconf/priority string critical
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean false
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 10.5.5.230
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.248.0.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 10.1.1.1
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 10.1.1.1
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string jfg
d-i netcfg/get_domain string wa-prod.org
d-i netcfg/hostname string jfg
```

(And yes, the network config is a valid one in real life)

Comment: Check out this [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=688273).

Comment: What OS/version are you trying to install (ie. what are you using as an .ISO file?)